# Batch issue with wmic and drive serial number

Tags: windows, for-loop, batch-file, cmd, wmic

Been working on this all day with no results, need to set a variable from a batch file for my hard drive serial. When I run this command from a batch `"wmic path win32_physicalmedia get SerialNumber /format:csv"` it gives results as:

```
Node,SerialNumber
WORK-PC, S1DHNSAF323341Z
WORK-PC,
```

Only need the serial to print out "S1DHNSAF323341Z" I then put it in a For statement with wmic as below but no output..
Please help, thanks for the help..Bill

```
For /F "skip=2 tokens=2 delims=," %%A in ('WMIC Path Win32_physicalmedia Get SerialNumber /FORMAT:csv') Do Set HDSerial=%%A 
echo. %HDSerial%
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
@echo off
setlocal
For /F "tokens=2 delims==" %%A in ('WMIC Path Win32_physicalmedia Get SerialNumber /value^|find "="') do (
 for %%B in (%%A) do (echo %%B)
)
```

Comment: +1, Explanation: An odd interaction of FOR /F with WMIC unicode output results in an extra unwanted carriage return at the end of each line that causes parsing problems. The extra FOR loop strips out the unwanted carriage return. ***NOTE:*** The pipe to FIND is not needed. Lines that don't have a 2nd token will be stripped out by the first FOR /F loop anyway.

Comment: Thank You very Much Matt!..Works perfect, was working on adding Find or Findstr but this will do the job, if I want to add a Do Set HDSerial=%%B How would I add that?

Comment: Got it worked out, and thanks Dave for the pipe to find not needed.

Comment: To mark this as solved, you can click the green tick under the arrows next to the question :)